# Check if record exists then insert new row in database table?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to improve the old code that I'm working on. The current code can be simplified and use SQL to process the insert. Here is example:

```
<!--- Check if user exists in Table 1 ---> 
<cfquery name="checkUser" datasource="#application.datasource#">
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM table1
    WHERE user_id = '#session.user_id#'
</cfquery>

<cfif !checkUser.recordcount>
    <cfset password = functions.encryptPsw("form.pswd") />
    <cfquery name="getInfo" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT fname, lname
        FROM contact
        WHERE userid = #session.user_id#
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery name="insertUser" datasource="#application.database#">
        INSERT INTO inter_work_tbl (
            user_id, 
            first_name, 
            last_name, 
            password
        ) VALUES (
            '#session.user_id#', 
            '#trim(getInfo.fname)#', 
            '#trim(getInfo.lname)#', 
            '#password#'
        )
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

I'm wondering if this can be done with `Sybase` SQL and use `IF NOT EXISTS` then run Insert statement? If anyone have good example or suggestions please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?  I don't know coldfusion so not sure I'm reading it correctly so ... what's the logic you're trying to implement?  if the record exists in `table` and `contract` then insert to `inter_work_tbl`? if the record doesn't already exist in `inter_work_tbl` then go ahead and insert?

Comment: @markp 16.0 / ase160

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but ... *cough* cfqueryparam *cough*  ;-)

Comment: To improve your old ColdFusion code you can use `cfqueryparam` tag  [https://helpx.adobe.com/in/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html] It will improve performance and security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know/work-with coldfusion so not sure I'm reading the logic correctly ...

- if record does not exist in `table1` but
- record does exit in `contact` then
- insert a row into `inter_work_tbl`

The general T-SQL query would look like (note: mixing T-SQL with references to the coldfusion variables):

```
insert into inter_work_tbl

      (user_id
      ,first_name
      ,last_name
      ,password)

select '#session.user_id#',
       c.fname,
       c.lname,
       '#password#'

from   contact c

where  c.userid = #session.user_id#
and    not exists(select  1
                  from    table1 t
                  where   t.user_id = c.userid)
```

Comment: Does Sybase have the same issues with [concurrent updates/inserts as sql server](https://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question says that you want to improve your code.  That being the case, let's start with this.  You have:

```
<cfif !checkUser.recordcount>
```

That's not really readable or intuitive.  Here is another way to express that condition:

```
<cfif checkUser.recordcount eq 0>
```

Next, in the unlikely event that you posted actual code, your checkUser query looks for records in table1 and if there are none, puts a record into a different table - inter_work_tbl.  That seems a bit dicey.

Next, you get information from a table called contact and insert it into your inter_work_tbl table.  Even if you think you will always have a record in the contact table, what if you don't?  Your insert query will crash due to an undefined variable.  Also, why do you need the name in table inter_work_tbl?  You already have in the contact table.  You are breaking normalization for no apparent reason.

As far as simplifying the code to use sql only, @markp's answer shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have a 50 reputation to comment, so I'm replying to this as an answer instead.  Sounds like you can simply use the sql `merge` statement to accomplish this.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/commands89.htm